# Why do musical tesla coils sound more like square waves?

Tags: sound, waveform, sine, tesla-coil, square

When people modulate their tesla coils to play music, it sounds like a very sharp square wave, as opposed to the electrical signal, a (roughly) sine wave. Why doesn't the tesla coil sound like a sine wave, which would match the electrical signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This modulation is done using an "interrupter", which turns the coil on and off at the right frequencies to generate the notes. The output of the interrupter is a square wave. The output from the topload is sinusoidal, but the frequency of each burst is too high for the human ear to perceive. Therefore you only hear the output from the interrupter.

Comment: could one make an "analog interrupter"?

Comment: Not really. The point is to turn the coil on and off at the right frequency to create what sounds like musical notes. You can apply a sine wave and adjust the frequency that way, but you still need to be able to turn the coil on and off, which means it would need to be converted to a square wave eventually.

Comment: @DerStrom8 This sounds quite like a keying waveform used in digital RF modulations. In this field, non-square wavefroms, such as raised cosine, are quite common, due to sidebands created by squares.

Comment: So, If i'm understanding this right, the interrupter is acting like a class D amplifier? https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5590

Comment: @tuskiomi no, the interrupter is simply a high-speed repeating switch. It feeds a HI/LO signal into logic chips, which turn the Tesla coil drivers on or off, thus turning the Tesla coil on or off. The interrupter is not an amplifier.

Comment: @DerStrom8 in theory, would a High-current class D amplifier work?

Comment: For an interrupter? Probably not. In order to modulate a Tesla coil there are a lot of things that need to be taken into account, the most important of which is the duty cycle and pulse width. If your duty cycle or pulse width is too high, you put a lot of strain on your driving transistors and will likely destroy them. Therefore interrupters are built to limit the pulse width and duty cycle to limits that won't damage your coil. Simply connecting a Class D amplifier doesn't give you any of this control, so you will probably damage your coil. You can't cut corners here.

Comment: A class D amplifier assumes that the load will ultimately behave in a predictable and linear fashion converting the switched current to air movement.  The lightning bolts produced by a Tesla coil behave in a fashion which is not predictable, much less linear, except on a really gross macroscopic scale.  If there is a major change to the drive waveform, it may take some milliseconds for the system to start behaving predictably at the new frequency.  If the drive waveform changes every few hundred milliseconds, it will be stable for long periods of time between.  If, however...

Comment: ...the drive waveform is a 25kHz carrier modulated at 500Hz, the system may never achieve a predictable state but may simply behave erratically and unpredictably.